# Problema con consulta de datos

Tags: php

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño problema con una consulta de php , tengo que hallar la suma total de todas las ventas de las oficinas que pertenecen a una empresa eh igualarla a a la variable que esta en sesión, para que cada información sea correspondiente al usuario (empresa) que inicie sesión.

La tabla cliente , tiene oficina,empresa,asesor,usuario nivel 2 y 3 que son los que realizan las ventas
la tabla cliente se relaciona con usuario el nivel 1 no vende es el encargado de recaudar el dinero la suma de ventas de los usuarios 2 y 3 y estos pertenecen a las oficinas que pertenecen a la empresa

```
$<?php 
$usuario_id = $_SESSION['empresa'];
$sql = "SELECT SUM(cliente.prima_total)as prima,cliente.oficina,cliente.empresa,cliente.usuario_id,usuario.idusuario,usuario.rol FROM cliente RIGHT JOIN usuario ON usuario.idusuario = cliente.usuario_id ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $fila['prima'];
```

Comment: Podrias hacer un ciclo while o for y suma cada una de las ventas

Comment: @christian puedes ayudarme, no entiendo como hacerlo

Comment: ok, que contiene la variable ```$fila['prima']```?

Comment: @christian el resultado de SELECT SUM(cliente.prima_total)as prima

Comment: @christian las oficinas pertenecen a una empresa y son las que hacen ventas , la consulta esta bien solo tengo que igualarla a la empresa que esta en sesión

Comment: esta bien mi respuesta? lo siento lo lei cuando ya lo termine

Comment: @christian no entiendo mucho por eso deje el código jeje es que no he podido hallar la forma de que me muestre la información de la persona que esta en sesión en cuanto a las ventas de sus oficinas

Comment: heee... no logro entender muy bien, lo que quieres es mostrar la informacion del que este en session?, como extra podrias poner lo que da el ```echo $fila['prima']```

Comment: @christian no es eso, mira tengo una tabla llamada cliente que se relaciona con la tabla usuario, la tabla usuario tiene un nivel 1 que es empresa, una empresa tiene muchas oficinas , cada oficina tiene usuarios nivel 2 y 3 que son los que realizan las ventas , el nivel 1 en este caso es la empresa por ende todas las ventas de las oficinas deben sumarse para que cuando el nivel 1 entre a su perfil vea el total de las ventas de sus oficinas , como te digo la consulta esta bien solo que va aparecer el mismo valor en todos los perfiles para ello es el uso de la variable sesión pero no he podido

Comment: haa bueno te voy a poner un ejemplo

Comment: @christian dale muchas gracias

Comment: ya esta, ve si eso es lo que quieres

Comment: La pregunta no es clara y no creo que se resuelva de la mejor manera trayendo varias filas y luego sumando en un bucle como sugiere @christian en su respuesta. ¿Acaso no se puede traer la suma directamente escribiendo la consulta adecuadamente? ¿Por qué habría que sumar a posteriori, cuando los SGBD tienen funciones como `SUM()`? Aunque el mayor problema aquí es *no saber explicar el problema*, podrías intentar una consulta de suma, aplicando los filtros que haga falta, tomando los datos de donde debas tomarlos.

Answer (score 2):

para eso lo haces con un ciclo `while` o `for` en este caso te voy a dar el ejemplo con un ciclo `while`

```
$total=0;    //inicializamos una variable que contendra el total
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $venta = $fila['ventas'] // aqui pones la fila en la que se encuentre las ventas
    $total+=$venta;
}
print($total);
```

esto hara la suma de todas las ventas

para hacer la seleccion segun la empresa deberias utilizar llaves foraneas o algun campo con el cual lo puedas relacionar. ejemplo

tienes una tabla usuarios y una tabla publicacion

en la usuarios tienes los campos *id*,*nombre*,*apellidos* y en la tabla publicacion tienes los campos *id*,*contenido*,**usuario**

al hacer la consulta tendras que elegir las publicaciones de cada ususario para eso utilizas el `where` de esta forma `"Select * from publicaciones Where 'juan'=usuario` esto te traera todas las publicaciones del usuario juan

si no es esto lo que quieres dejamelo saber

Comment: He votado en contra de esta respuesta porque te lanzas a aportar una solución sin que se entienda del todo el problema planteado. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué habría que traer todas las filas para luego sumar a posteriori, en un bucle, cuando los SGBD disponen de una función `SUM()`?

Comment: Si lo se pero el no.obtiene  el resultado deseado o eso es lo que dice la pregunta, por  eso he tratado de ayudarlo de otras formas, si @Codej me dice que en realidad si obtiene la suma pues eliminaré eso y me quedaré con la segunda parte, además es cierto que la pregunta no es muy clara

Comment: Ya, pero no todos los problemas se resuelven de cualquier manera, la optimización es importante. Imagínate que ese resultado conste de miles o decenas de miles de filas, estarías trayendo todas esas filas para luego hacer un conteo que pudiste hacer directamente con `SUM()`. En un entorno concurrente o con limitaciones de memoria, de ancho de banda, etc, eso podría tener graves consecuencias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estimado ya logre resolverlo pero igual muchas gracias a todos